# Como fazer e calcular a Tabela de distribuição de frequência em R?

Tags: r, matemática

Estou tentando fazer a **Tabela de distribuição de frequência** em R, porém, não estou conseguindo, devido á algumas formulas e cálculos que eu não consigo implementar no R.

A estrutura da tabela de distribuição de frequência é a seguinte:

```
-------------------------------------
|Dados | Xi | Fi | Fr | Fac | Xi.Fi |
|      |    |    |    |     |       |
|      |    |    |    |     |       |
-------------------------------------
```

Eu não sei como calcular os valores de `Xi`, `Fi`, `Fr`, `Fac`, `Xi.Fi` e não entendi muito bem o que eles representam nesta tabela.

Há também outros cálculos que deve ser feito que é *Amplitude*, *Quantidade de Elementos* e *Tamanho do intervalo*. No qual tive as mesmas dificuldades para fazer também.

## Dados

O **ROL** que estou usando para fazer a tabela de distribuição de frequência é este correspondente a idade dos alunos:

[image: Dados idade - Tabela]

Os valores do ROL que uso no R são:

```
18 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 20 20 22 23 24 26 26 30 32
```

## Pergunta

Como eu posso fazer a Tabela de distribuição de frequência desses dados acima no R?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pra primeira parte da questão, o código abaixo pode te ajudar

```
library(dplyr)
dados <- c(18,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,20,20,22,23,24,26,26,30,32)
tabela <- data.frame(t(table(dados)))[,-1]
tabela$dados <- as.numeric(levels(tabela$dados))
tabela <- tabela %>% 
  mutate(Fr = 100*Freq/sum(Freq),
         Fac = cumsum(Freq),
         Xi.Fi = dados*Freq)
tabela
```

quanto suas dúvidas, `Xi`e `Dados` da estrutura da tabela que você colocou, é a mesma coisa, são todos os valores que sua variável pode assumir. `Fi` representa a frequência que cada valor da variável ocorre. `Fr` é a frequência relativa, `Faq` é a frequência acumulada e `Xi.Fi` é a multiplicação de cada valor da variável pela sua respectiva frequência.

Sugiro que você pegue algum material ou livro de Estatística Básica. Você encontrará essa parte que explica a criação de tabela de frequências.

Quanto à segunda parte, dos outros cálculos, o mesmo livro (ou material) deve ter uma parte para criação dessa tabela com intervalos. Lá você verá o passo a passo para a criação da mesma, aí você conseguirá responder a *Amplitude, Quantidade de Elementos e Tamanho do intervalo*.

Mais informações a respeito [aqui](http://rpubs.com/EstatBasica/Cap2).

Answer (score 0):

Se não me engano, ao inserir os dados pode usar uma função rep() para poupar tempo e trabalho. Por exemplo para o número 19 e 20 basta fazer:

dados = c(rep(19,11),
rep(20,2))

Assim o RStudio coloca automaticamente o número 19 e 20, 11 e 2 vezes respetivamente(De notar que se a variável for uma palavra tem que vir entre aspas para não dar erro).

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).